# Pop out the whole dic if element of 1st dic in list is repeated?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Here I have a list of dic, where I want to remove duplicates which is equal to 1st element of dic.
Input :

```
data  = [

    [
          [{'color': '1'},{'color': '0'},{'color': '2'},{'color': '1'}],
          [{'color': '2'},{'color': '3'},{'color': '2'},{'color': '5'}],
          [{'color': '1'},{'color': '1'},{'color': '3'},{'color': '3'}]
    ],

    [
          [{'color': '1'},{'color': '1'},{'color': '4'},{'color': '4'}],
          [{'color': '4'},{'color': '3'},{'color': '1'},{'color': '4'}],
          [{'color': '7'},{'color': '1'},{'color': '7'},{'color': '1'}]
    ]

        ]
```

I have tried and got the expected output, Is there any pythonic way to achieve the same ?

Code :

```
new = [] ; 
for i in data:
    master = []
    for j in i:
        temp = []
        for k in j:
            if j[0]['color'] != k['color']:
                temp.append(k)
        temp.insert(0,j[0])
        master.append(temp)
    new.append(master)
print(new)
```

Expected Output :

```
data  = [

    [
          [{'color': '1'},{'color': '0'},{'color': '2'}],
          [{'color': '2'},{'color': '3'},{'color': '5'}],
          [{'color': '1'},{'color': '3'},{'color': '3'}]
    ],

    [
          [{'color': '1'},{'color': '4'},{'color': '4'}],
          [{'color': '4'},{'color': '3'},{'color': '5'}],
          [{'color': '7'},{'color': '1'},{'color': '1'}]
    ]     
    ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for all the temporary lists:

```
for item in data:
    for i,subitem in enumerate(item):
        item[i] = [item[i][0]] + [dct for dct in item[i][1:]
                                  if dct['color'] != item[i][0]['color']]
```

Basically it just iterates through each of the subitems and replaces it with its first item plus the rest of the items that don't have the same value.

Although it's ugly, you can even reduce it to a one-liner (for illustrative purposes only... I wouldn't recommend it because readability):

```
data = [[[item[i][0]] + [dct for dct in item[i][1:] if dct['color'] != item[i][0]['color']] for i,subitem in enumerate(item)] for item in data]
```

Comment: @akashkarothiya Yes, it's a continuation of the previous line.

Comment: @akashkarothiya Print `data`, not `item`. `item` is a temp variable used in the `for` loop.